# JSONArray constructor does not function

Tags: android, json, arrays

I'm experiencing some problem loading a JSONArray on the Android. I've constructed the JSON string with Gson and I've checked this online to see whether it is valid. It validates on various online JSON-syntax checkers.

The JSONArray constructor I want to use seems to throw an error when I feed it with a JSONString.

The full error trace from the JSONArray(String json) constructor which causes a problem looks like this.

```
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412): org.json.JSONException: Value {"posisjon":"OK","spenning":"0.23","driftsmerking":"1420 10 04","adresse":"KANEBOG�SEN 4","kompNr":"1420","objektnummer":"56569.0","typebetegnelse":"KO500","longitude":"16.5598512563035","latitude":"68.7786964342854","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","fabrikat":"NEBB"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107) 
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at net.lovholm.kraftwerk.Kraftwerk.onCreate(Kraftwerk.java:66)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-03 15:14:44.290: WARN/System.err(412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is an excerpt of the code where the error begins.

```
try {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(finalString);

    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i);
        try {
        Kabelskap ks = getKabelskapFromJSON(jsonObj);
        skap.put(ks.objektnummer, ks);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A System.out.println(finalString) gives me this result in the DDMS. The System.out.println() skips long parts of the text. I would presume that the DDMS LogCat is using a charset not supporting Norwegian special letters, and not writing the whole string to log.

```
11-30 11:02:27.888: INFO/System.out(4304): {"driftsmerking":"1420 10 04","objektnummer":"56569.0","adresse":"KANEBOG�SEN 4","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"KO500","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1420","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7786964342854","longitude":"16.5598512563035"}{"driftsmerking":"4416 01 04","objektnummer":"246349.0","adresse":"NONS�SEN","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO300","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4416","kommune":"1911 KV�FJORD","latitude":"68.7367985627796","longitude":"16.2694481350258"}{"driftsmerking":"4080 05 02","objektnummer":"275933.0","adresse":"KV�FJORD PLANTESKOLE VEKSTHUS","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO700","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4080","kommune":"1911 KV�FJORD","latitude":"68.7712454761326","longitude":"16.1901046355049"}{"driftsmerking":"1383 01 02","objektnummer":"150951.0","adresse":"SKILLEVN. 13","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.4","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1383","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7781436806564","longitude":"16.5643438120601"}{"driftsmerking":"4085 07 02","objektnummer":"275122.0","adresse":"MATHUSET","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"70","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4085","kommune":"1911 KV�FJORD","latitude":"68.7721426826508","longitude":"16.1785193494225"}{"driftsmerking":"3410 05 12","objektnummer":"35184.0","adresse":"HANS EGEDESGT. 20 (ERIKSGATE)","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"3410","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7980203542316","longitude":"16.538182961594"}{"driftsmerking":"0800 06 10","objektnummer":"266928.0","adresse":"GAMNES V/MAGNE HARALD OLSEN","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO35","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.8206299498345","longitude":"16.4915959572276"}{"driftsmerking":"2580 02 02","objektnummer":"186379.0","adresse":"RESSAN","fabrikat":"ELMEK","typebetegnelse":"50 CM","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"2580","kommune":"1913 SK�NLAND","latitude":"68.6729130202412","longitude":"17.127746958547"}{"driftsmerking":"1500 10 06","objektnummer":"193875.0","adresse":"TUVSLETTVN. 9","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO500","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1500","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.74741783798","longitude":"16.5517037722856"}{"driftsmerking":"3282 02 02","objektnummer":"35547.0","adresse":"TEGEB�RVN. 12B","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"3282","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7991934883357","longitude":"16.5033927383319"}{"driftsmerking":"1430 05 02","objektnummer":"116375.0","adresse":"�VERLAND 2","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO700","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1430","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7759663213591","longitude":"16.5611455110691"}{"driftsmerking":"4150 05 06","objektnummer":"275496.0","adresse":" NYVN. 21","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO500","spenning":"0.4","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4150","kommune":"1911 KV�FJORD","latitude":"68.7741925557284","longitude":"16.1726621696438"}{"driftsmerking":"1486 07 02","objektnummer":"162192.0","adresse":"ROHOLTVN. 7","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO 700","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1486","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7550368601091","longitude":"16.5679658964195"}{"driftsmerking":"3025 02 06 / 3060 /","objektnummer":"35174.0","adresse":"HANS EGEDESGT. 6 (HVEDINGSGATE)","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"3025","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7994885383443","longitude":"16.5414817371666"}{"driftsmerking":"7045 03 06","objektnummer":"251410.0","adresse":"KONGSVIKDALEN","fabrikat":"","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"7045","kommune":"1852 TJELDSUND","latitude":"68.5682671357777","longitude":"16.2428412985428"}{"driftsmerking":"3010 03 02","objektnummer":"35143.0","adresse":"6.DIVISJONSGT. 10","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO500",
```

I've already created a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319350/loading-json-from-string-into-jsonarray-on-android) here, and I've followed up the feedback from the answers, but it seems like another problem. Anyhow, perhaps this questions may fill in some blanks.

--- update --- 
The JSON string which is read by the system looks like this (but is longer). Should an JSON Array be encapsulated by [] for each element or just in the beginning? Is there som way of reading a JSON-collection into a JSONArray structure.

```
[{"driftsmerking":"1420 10 04","objektnummer":"56569.0","adresse":"KANEBOGÅSEN 4","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"KO500","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1420","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7786964342854","longitude":"16.5598512563035"},{"driftsmerking":"4416 01 04","objektnummer":"246349.0","adresse":"NONSÅSEN","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO300","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4416","kommune":"1911 KVÆFJORD","latitude":"68.7367985627796","longitude":"16.2694481350258"},{"driftsmerking":"4080 05 02","objektnummer":"275933.0","adresse":"KVÆFJORD PLANTESKOLE VEKSTHUS","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO700","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4080","kommune":"1911 KVÆFJORD","latitude":"68.7712454761326","longitude":"16.1901046355049"},{"driftsmerking":"1383 01 02","objektnummer":"150951.0","adresse":"SKILLEVN. 13","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.4","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"1383","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7781436806564","longitude":"16.5643438120601"},{"driftsmerking":"4085 07 02","objektnummer":"275122.0","adresse":"MATHUSET","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"70","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"4085","kommune":"1911 KVÆFJORD","latitude":"68.7721426826508","longitude":"16.1785193494225"},{"driftsmerking":"3410 05 12","objektnummer":"35184.0","adresse":"HANS EGEDESGT. 20 (ERIKSGATE)","fabrikat":"NEBB","typebetegnelse":"","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"3410","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.7980203542316","longitude":"16.538182961594"},{"driftsmerking":"0800 06 10","objektnummer":"266928.0","adresse":"GAMNES V/MAGNE HARALD OLSEN","fabrikat":"ABB","typebetegnelse":"KO35","spenning":"0.23","posisjon":"OK","kompNr":"","kommune":"1901 HARSTAD","latitude":"68.8206299498345","longitude":"16.4915959572276"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string in your log isn't an array (arrays in JSON are enclosed with square brackets). It's just an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
try {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(finalString);

    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i);
        try {
        Kabelskap ks = getKabelskapFromJSON(jsonObj);
        skap.put(ks.objektnummer, ks);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(finalString);
            Kabelskap ks = getKabelskapFromJSON(jsonObj);
            skap.put(ks.objektnummer, ks);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This isn't the cleanest way, but it's works :)

---

*Edit*

A better way:

```
if(finalString!=null && !finalString.isEmpty()) {
    if(finalString..startsWith("["))
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(finalString);

            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                try {
                    Kabelskap ks = getKabelskapFromJSON(jsonObj);
                    skap.put(ks.objektnummer, ks);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(finalString);
            Kabelskap ks = getKabelskapFromJSON(jsonObj);
            skap.put(ks.objektnummer, ks);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```